# start erlang otp application from makefile

Tags: erlang

I've created an erlang application where I can use application:start(Name) to successfully start the application.

I tried to create a makefile step that uses rebar to compile, and then manually start the application. But it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have now:

```
all: compile start

compile:
    ./rebar compile

start:
    erl -s application load shoutcast -s application start shoutcast
```

All this does is loads up an interactive erlang shell

Comment: The third argument of -s (shoutcast in this case) is sent as a list. So your code will call application:start([shoutcast]) which does not work. You could write a function that does this or perhaps look into creating a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Aplication:start(Name)
```

calls

```
Name:start/2
```

while the -s flag calls

```
Name:start() or Name:start([arg1, arg2, ...]).
```

So, I don't think you can successfully invoke Application in this way. Assuming you don't want to create a release and boot file, you could (I think) add a method to you application module, start/0

```
-module(shoutcast).

-behaviour(application).

%% Application callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

%% Allow for erl -s invocation 
-export([start/0]).

 ... Snip ...

start() ->
    application:start(shoutcast).

... Snip ...
```

Then within your makefile

```
erl -s shoutcast
```

I'm not sure if this violates a best practice, but it should work.

Comment: I was looking for the "proper" way to do it, but this is actually fine for my needs, so thanks for that.

Comment: I think this acceptable and not too far from standard. For example, the cowboy examples include modules which do nothing but expose a start/0 which, in turn, calls application:start(cowboy). See: (https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/examples/echo_get/src/echo_get.erl)

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to keep useful things in common Makefile
https://github.com/virtan/erlang-makefile